# moving values from one dataframe to another, depending on value of a variable

Tags: r, merge, reshape

Not being familiar with R, I've got the following problem: I want to add the values `probeposition` from the dataframe `mlpa` to the dataframe `patients`, with the values of `probeposition` being linked by values being present both in `mlpa` and `patients` (i.e. `probe` and `patprobe`). As far as I've seen, this problem is not covered by the usual data management tutorials.

```
#mlpa:
probe <- c(12,15,18,19)
probeposition <- c(100,1200,500,900)
mlpa = data.frame(probe = probe, probeposition = probeposition)
#patients:
patid <- c('AT', 'GA', 'TT', 'AG', 'GG', 'TA')
patprobe <- c(12, 12, NA, NA, 18, 19)
patients = data.frame(patid = patid, patprobe = patprobe)

#And that's what I finally want:
patprobeposition = c(100, 100, NA, NA, 500, 900)  
patients$patprobeposition = patprobeposition
```

### Update

Upon the response of Andrie, I got aware that that I have to mention that there are several "probes" in the patients dataset, so actually the data would more look like this (in fact, there would not only be probe1 and probe2, but probe1-probe4):

```
mlpa <- data.frame(probe = c(12,15,18,19),
                   probeposition = c(100,1200,500,900) ) 
patients <- data.frame(patid = c('AT', 'GA', 'TT', 'AG', 'GG', 'TA'),
                       probe1 = c(12, 12, NA, NA, 18, 19), 
                       probe2 = c(15, 15, NA, NA, 19, 19) )
```

And what I want is this:

```
patients <- data.frame(patid = c('AT', 'GA', 'TT', 'AG', 'GG', 'TA'),   
                       probe1 = c(12, 12, NA, NA, 18, 19), 
                       probe2 = c(15, 15, NA, NA, 19, 19), 
                       position1 = c(100, 100, NA, NA, 500, 900), 
                       position2 = c(1200, 1200, NA, NA, 900, 900))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very easily using `merge`, which takes two data frames and joins them on common columns or row names.

The easiest way to get `merge` to work, is to make sure you have matching columns names where those columns refer to the same information. To be specific, I have renamed your column `patprobe` to `probe`:

```
mlpa <- data.frame(
  probe = c(12,15,18,19),
  probeposition = c(100,1200,500,900)
)

patients <- data.frame(
  patid = c('AT', 'GA', 'TT', 'AG', 'GG', 'TA'),
  probe = c(12, 12, NA, NA, 18, 19)
)
```

Now you can call `merge`.  However, note that the default values of `merge` only returns matching rows (in database terminology this is an *inner join*). What you want, is to include **all** of the rows in `patients` (a left outer join). You do this by specifying `all.x=TRUE`:

```
merge(patients, mlpa, all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)

  probe patid probeposition
1    12    AT           100
2    12    GA           100
3    18    GG           500
4    19    TA           900
5    NA    TT            NA
6    NA    AG            NA
```

Comment: Thanks Andrie! Unfortunately I was't aware that I have to mention that there are several "probes" in the patients dataset (see edit in the question). As far as I see, merge() doesn't work for that situation, right?

Answer (score 0):

Install the `reshape2` package and try the following:

```
require(reshape2)
m.patients = melt(patients)
m.patients = merge(m.patients, mlpa, 
                   by.x = "value", 
                   by.y = "probe", 
                   all = TRUE)
reshape(m.patients, direction="wide", 
        timevar="variable", idvar="patid")
```

This should give you output like the following, which can be cleaned up to match your desired output.

```
   patid value.probe1 probeposition.probe1 value.probe2 probeposition.probe2
1     AT           12                  100           15                 1200
2     GA           12                  100           15                 1200
5     GG           18                  500           19                  900
7     TA           19                  900           19                  900
9     TT           NA                   NA           NA                   NA
10    AG           NA                   NA           NA                   NA
```

### Update

Of course, you can also do it all with the `reshape2` package as below:

```
m.patients = melt(patients, id.vars="patid", variable_name="time")
m.patients = melt(merge(m.patients, mlpa, by.x = "value", 
                        by.y = "probe", all = TRUE))
dcast(m.patients, patid ~ variable + time )
```

Which results in:

```
  patid value_probe1 value_probe2 probeposition_probe1 probeposition_probe2
1    AG           NA           NA                   NA                   NA
2    AT           12           15                  100                 1200
3    GA           12           15                  100                 1200
4    GG           18           19                  500                  900
5    TA           19           19                  900                  900
```

### Update 2: Using Base R Reshape

You can also avoid using the `reshape2` package entirely.

```
patients.l = reshape(patients, direction="long", idvar="patid", 
                     varying=c("probe1", "probe2"), sep="")
reshape(merge(patients.l, mlpa, all = TRUE), direction="wide", 
        idvar="patid", timevar="time")
```

This gets you closest to your desired output:

```
   patid probe.1 probeposition.1 probe.2 probeposition.2
1     AT      12             100      15            1200
2     GA      12             100      15            1200
5     GG      18             500      19             900
7     TA      19             900      19             900
9     TT      NA              NA      NA              NA
10    AG      NA              NA      NA              NA
```